# Why is "//*" the only xPath query that works when I'm parsing this XML in R using the XML-package?

Tags: r, xpath, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I'm parsing a Swedish library catalogue using R and the XML-package. Using the library's API, I'm getting XML back from a url containing my query.

I'd like to use xPath queries to parse each record, but everything I do with xPath of the XML-package returns blank lists, everything except "//*". I'm no expert in either xml-parsing nor xPath, but I suspect that it has to do with the xml that my API returns to me.

This is a simple example of one single post in the catalogue:

```
library(XML)

example.url <- "http://libris.kb.se/sru/swepub?version=1.1&operation=searchRetrieve&query=mat:dok&maximumRecords=1&recordSchema=mods"
doc = xmlParse(example.url)

# Title
works <- xmlRoot(doc)[[4]][["record"]][["recordData"]][["mods"]][["titleInfo"]][["title"]][[1]]
doesntwork <- getNodeSet(doc, "//title")

# The only xPath that returns anything
onlythisworks <- getNodeSet(doc, "//*")
```

If this has something to do with namespaces ([as these answers sugests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876571/how-can-i-use-xpath-querying-using-rs-xml-library)), all I understan about it is that the API returns data that seems to have namespaces defined in the initial tag, and that I could use that, but this doesn't help me:

```
# Namespaces are confusing:
title <- getNodeSet(xmlRoot(doc), "//xsi:title", namespaces = c(xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"))
```

Here's (again) [the example return data](http://libris.kb.se/sru/swepub?version=1.1&operation=searchRetrieve&query=mat:dok&maximumRecords=1&recordSchema=mods) that I'm trying to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the right namespace.
Try the following

```
doesntwork <- getNodeSet(doc, "//mods:title")
#[[1]]
#<title>Horizontal Slot Waveguides for Silicon Photonics Back-End Integration [Elektronisk resurs]</title> 
#
#[[2]]
#<title>TRITA-ICT/MAP AVH, 2014:17                      \
#                           </title> 
#
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

BTW: I usually get the namespaces via

```
nsDefs=xmlNamespaceDefinitions(doc,simplify = TRUE,recursive=TRUE)
```

But this throws an error in your case. It complains that there are `different URIs for the same name space prefix`. According to 
[this site](http://www.sitepoint.com/xml-namespaces-explained/) this does not seem to be good coding style.

---

Update as per OP's comment

I am myself not an `xml` expert, but here is my take: You can define default namespaces via `<tag xmlns=URI>`. Non default namespaces are of the form `<tag xmlns:a=URI>` with `a` being the respective namespace name.
The problem with your document is that there are two different default namespaces. The first being in `<searchRetrieveResponse xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/" ... >`. The second is in `<mods xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" ... >`. Also, you will find the second default namespace URI in the first tag as `xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3"` (where it is non-default). This seems rather messy. Now, the `<title>` tag is within the `<mods>` tag. I think that the default namespace defined in `<mods>` gets overridden by the non default namespace of `searchRetrieveResponse` (because they have the same URI). So although `<mods>` and all following tags (like `<title>`) seems to have default namespaces they actually have the `xmlns:mods` namespace. But this does not apply to the tag `<numberOfRecords>` (because it's outside of `<mods>`). You can access this node via

```
getNodeSet(doc, "//ns:numberOfRecords",
       namespaces = c(ns="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/"))
```

Here you extract the default namespace defined in `<searchRetrieveResponse>` and give it a name (`ns` in our case). Then you can explicitly use the default namespace name in your xPath query.

Comment: I need to make time to learn about this namespace business. Good link to start out with. Thank you @cryo111 . xmlNamespaceDefinitions() does list the namespaces in the above example like this: `nsDefs=xmlNamespaceDefinitions(doc,simplify = TRUE)`, without recursive.

Comment: How should one know that it's the mods-namespace that I should use? Now I can only xPath to tags with the mods:-namespace, in spite of trying all other declared namespaces, I can't figure out how to make an xPath to <numberOfRecords> or <record> that are not nested within the <mods>-tag...

Comment: Wow. Thanks a million. Basically, I have to work around my xml-response being messy. I found [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986013.aspx) instructive for general namespace-stuff. But when I want to loop through books I'll have to skip between namespaces. Building on your update above @cryo111, I got this line working with multiple namespaces: `getNodeSet(doc, "//ns:record[2]//mods:title",
           namespaces = c(ns="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/", mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3"))`, and can go ahead and scrap the data that I want. All is now well. Thanks again!

Comment: @nJGL You are welcome. Good link on namespaces that you have provided.