# getNodeSet {XML} not working when XML root node contains "xlmns" attribute

Tags: r, xml-parsing

I have an xml document like this

```
<MasterDataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/MasterDataSet.xsd">
    <t_attribute>

        <class_id>2</class_id>

        <description>Latitude</description>

    </t_attribute>

    <t_object>
        <name>Ship</name>
    </t_object>
...
</MasterDataSet>
```

With many "t_attribute" and "t_object" nodes. I want to get a node set of all the "t_object" nodes so I use getNodeSet with xPath:

```
library("XML")
emtree0 <- xmlParse("EM0.xml", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
onlyobjects <- getNodeSet(emtree0,"/MasterDataSet//t_object")
```

But this returns an empty list.

However if I modify the XML file to look like this, i.e. if I remove the xmlns attribute, it works perfectly:

```
<MasterDataSet>
    <t_attribute>
...
```

Any suggestions to make the code work without having to remove the xmlns attribute?

Comment: you could try `getNodeSet(emtree0,"/x:MasterDataSet//x:t_object",namespaces=c("x"="http://tempuri.org/MasterDataSet.xsd"))`

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876571/how-can-i-use-xpath-querying-using-rs-xml-library/3877167#3877167 might be helpful

Comment: @timelyportfolio Thanks a lot! It worked perfectly