# R XML xpath queries return NULL or list()

Tags: r, xml, xpath

I would like to extract data as dataframes from an XML file available under: http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P43405.xml

I only get back empty string although I think that the xpath queries are okay.

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
url <- "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P43405.xml"
urldata <- getURL(url)
xmlfile <- xmlParse(urldata)

# some xpath queries
xmlfile["//entry/comment[@type='function']/text"]
xmlfile["//entry/comment[@type='PTM']/text"]

xpathSApply(xmlfile,"//uniprot/entry",xmlGetAttr, 'dataset')
xpathSApply(xmlfile,"//uniprot/entry",xmlValue)
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks, Frank

Comment: Can you add a sample of the XML data that you're reading from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces are missing:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

url <- "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P43405.xml"
urldata <- getURL(url)
xmlfile <- xmlParse(urldata)

getNodeSet(xmlfile, "//entry//comment")
namespaces <- c(ns="http://uniprot.org/uniprot")
getNodeSet(xmlfile, "//ns:entry//ns:comment", namespaces)

getNodeSet(xmlfile, "//ns:entry//ns:comment[@type='PTM']/ns:text", namespaces)

xpathSApply(xmlfile,"//ns:uniprot/ns:entry",xmlGetAttr, 'dataset', namespaces=namespaces)
xpathSApply(xmlfile,"//ns:uniprot/ns:entry",xmlValue, namespaces=namespaces)
```

References:

`?xpathApply`

[How can I use xpath querying using R's XML library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876571/how-can-i-use-xpath-querying-using-rs-xml-library?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! YEs, the namespaces were missing. I added some additional code. Maybe that will help others to get familiar with XML.

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

url <- "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P43405.xml"
urldata <- getURL(url)
xmlfile <- xmlParse(urldata)

getNodeSet(xmlfile, "//entry//comment")

# one needs the name space here
namespaces <- c(ns="http://uniprot.org/uniprot")

# extract all comments, make a data frame
comments.uniprot <- getNodeSet(xmlfile, "//ns:entry//ns:comment", namespaces)
comments.dataframe <- as.data.frame(sapply(comments.uniprot, xmlValue))
comments.attributes <- as.data.frame(sapply(comments.uniprot, xmlGetAttr,'type'))
comments.all <- cbind(comments.attributes,comments.dataframe)

# only extract PTM comments
PTMs <- getNodeSet(xmlfile, "//ns:entry//ns:comment[@type='PTM']/ns:text", namespaces)
PTMs2 <- sapply(PTMs, xmlValue)
PTMs2.dataframe <- as.data.frame(PTMs2)


xpathSApply(xmlfile,"//ns:uniprot/ns:entry",xmlGetAttr, 'dataset', namespaces=namespaces)
xpathSApply(xmlfile,"//ns:uniprot/ns:entry/ns:accession",xmlValue, namespaces=namespaces)
```